# Santa's Decision

Tags: code-golf, string, parsing

## Santa's Decision:

In this challenge, you will help Santa Claus decide whether somebody on their list has been naughty or nice, and subsequently get `coal` or `toys`.

But unfortunately, Santa is unorganised, in some of his entries, the `naughty`, `nice`  and `name` fields are in the wrong order.

### Input

Input will come in the following, interchangeable format:

- the person's name (cannot contain a colon, only `a-zA-Z0-9`)
- the word `naughty` followed directly by a colon and an non-negative integer representing the amount of times Santa caught you being naughty
- the word `nice` followed directly by a colon and an non-negative integer representing the amount of times Santa caught you being nice

All separated with a single whitespace (ASCII 32) between each of them.

Additionally, the name will have no whitespace between the parts of the name `Santa Claus` -> `SantaClaus`.

### Bonus:

- **(25%)**: He is Santa Claus, so he needs to check the list *twice*, and make sure there are no duplicates. (In which case, it just gets the first scores that user has)

### Example:

```
Quill naughty:4 nice:0
naughty:0 Doorknob nice:3
naughty:2 Quill nice:6
nice:3 balpha naughty:3
pops nice:4 naughty:2
```

### Output:

The output should consist of:

The name of the person followed by:

- If there's more points in `naughty`, then `coal`:
- If there's more points in `nice`, then `toys`.
- But if `naughty` and `nice` are equal, then `needs more data`

  #### Example output:
- With organisation bonus and duplicate removal bonus:

```
Quill coal
Doorknob toys
balpha needs more data
pops toys
```

- Without bonus:

```
Quill coal
Doorknob toys
Quill toys
balpha needs more data
pops toys
```

## Lowest byte count wins!

Comment: There's also a typo in the test cases. You misspelled our glorious mod [DorkNoob](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/5844/31625)'s name :^)

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Can we assume nobody's name is `naughty` or `nice`?

Comment: Nope, naughty or nice are valid names

Comment: Does the output have to be space-separated, or can it be in a list?

Comment: Space separated

Comment: Just curious: why did you choose to eliminate duplicates instead of adding their totals?  Too complex?

Comment: That's a good idea... I guess there's always next time...

Comment: *"balpha needs more data"* That sounds about right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Pyth, 68 bytes - 25% = 51

```
V.zI-hA.g}\:kcNdY=+YGjd+G@c"needs more data
coal
toys"b._-Fmsecd\:SH
```

Try it online: [Demonstration](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V.zI-hA.g%7D%5C%3AkcNdY%3D%2BYGjd%2BG%40c%22needs+more+data%0Acoal%0Atoys%22b._-Fmsecd%5C%3ASH&input=Quill+naughty%3A4+nice%3A0%0Anaughty%3A0+Doorknob+nice%3A3%0Anaughty%3A2+Quill+nice%3A6%0Anice%3A3+balpha+naughty%3A3%0Apops+nice%3A4+naughty%3A2&debug=0)

Answer (score 5):

## Julia, <s>176</s> 169 bytes

```julia
s->for l=split(s,"\n") M(r)=parse(matchall(r,l)[1]);g=M(r"e:\K\d+");b=M(r"y:\K\d+");println(replace(l,r" *\w+:\d+ *","")," ",g>b?"toys":b>g?"coal":"needs more data")end
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts a string and prints the result to STDOUT. To call it, give it a name, e.g. `f=s->...`.

Ungolfed:

```julia
function santa(s::AbstractString)
    # Split the input on newlines and process each line separately
    for l in split(s, "\n")
        # Define a function to get the number from the result of a
        # regular expression match
        M(r) = parse(matchall(r, l)[1])

        # Goodness
        g = M(r"e:\K\d+")

        # Badness
        b = M(r"y:\K\d+")

        # Get the name by replacing the naughty and nice specifications
        # with empty strings and print the line to STDOUT
        println(replace(l, r" *\w+:\d+ *", ""), " ",
                g > b ? "toys" : b > g ? "coal" : "needs more data")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

## Pyth - 64 bytes

Will try to use packed strings.

```
jmj\ +hK.g@k\:cd\ @c"needs more data
coal
toys"b._-Fmseck\:SeK.z
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jmj%5C+%2BhK.g%40k%5C%3Acd%5C+%40c%22needs+more+data%0Acoal%0Atoys%22b._-Fmseck%5C%3ASeK.z&input=naughty%3A0+Doorknob+nice%3A3%0AQuill+naughty%3A4+nice%3A0%0Anice%3A3+balpha+naughty%3A3%0Apops+nice%3A4+naughty%3A2&debug=0).

Comment: This language is sufficiently advanced technology.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, <s>138</s> <s>113</s> <s>105</s> <s>103</s> <s>102</s> 96 - 25% = 72

*includes +1 for `-p`*

```
s/ *\w*(.):(\d+) */$$1=$2,()/eg;$$_++?$_='':s/\n/$".('needs more data',toys,coal)[$e<=>$y].$&/e
```

## Less golfed:

```
s/ *\w*(.):(\d+) */$$1=$2,()/eg;    # strip naughty/nice, set $a to naughty, $i to nice
                                    # $_ is now the input name followed by \n
$$_++ ? $_='' :                     # only output once per name
s/\n/                               # replace newlines with:
  $".                               # a space,
  ('needs more data',toys,coal)     # one of these strings,
  [$e<=>$y]                         # indexed by -1, 0 or 1
  .$&                               # and the matched newline.
/ex                                 # (/x only for legibility)
```

---

- *update 113*

  - save 25 bytes by using 1 letter from `nice` or `naughty` as variable name;
  - loose 5 bytes by fixing bug when name is last
- *update 105* save 8 bytes by using `<=>` to index a list of output strings.
- *update 103* save 2 bytes by using regex to append output string
- *update 102* save 1 byte by using last letter of `nice` or `naughty` instead of 2nd.
- *update 96* save 6 bytes by changing `$$_ ? ... : ($$_++, ...)` into `$$_++ ? ... : ...` 
  *(why didn't I see that before).*

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>144</s> <s>123</s> 155 * .75 = 116.25 bytes

```
->s{d={}
s.split("
").map{|l|
a=l.split
b=a.grep /:/
i,j,v=(b.sort*'').scan(/\d+/)+a-b
d[v]||(d[v]=0
puts v+' '+['needs more data','coal','toys'][i<=>j])}}
```

Thanks to histocrat for suggesting `grep` method.

**164 * .75 = 123 bytes**

```
->s{d={}
s.split("
").map{|l|
a=l.split
b=a.select{|t|t[?:]}
i,j,v=(b.sort*'').scan(/\d+/)+a-b
d[v]||(d[v]=0
puts v+' '+['needs more data','coal','toys'][i<=>j])}}
```

**144 bytes**

```
->s{puts s.split("
").map{|l|b=(a=l.split).select{|t|t[?:]};i,j=(b.sort*'').scan(/\d+/);(a-b)[0]+' '+['needs more data','coal','toys'][i<=>j]}}
```

**Ungolfed**

```
->s{
  d={}
  s.split("
  ").map{ |l|
    a = l.split
    b = a.grep /:/
    i, j, v = (b.sort * '').scan(/\d+/) + a-b
    d[v] ||
      (d[v]=0
       puts v + ' ' + ['needs more data','coal','toys'][i<=>j]
      )
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
# Assign the anonymous function to a variable
f = ->s{d={}
s.split("
").map{|l|
a=l.split
b=a.grep /:/
i,j,v=(b.sort*'').scan(/\d+/)+a-b
d[v]||(d[v]=0
puts v+' '+['needs more data','coal','toys'][i<=>j])}}

f["Quill naughty:4 nice:0
naughty:0 Doorknob nice:3
naughty:2 Quill nice:6
nice:3 balpha naughty:3
pops nice:4 naughty:2"]

Quill coal
Doorknob toys
balpha needs more data
pops toys
```

Comment: `.select{|t|t[?:]}` can be golfed to `.grep(/:/)`

Comment: @histocrat Wow i totally forgot that method. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 174 bytes - 25% bonus = 130.5 score

```js
s=>s.split`
`.map(l=>l.split` `.map(p=>(m=p.match(/\w:\d+/))?(n=+m[0].slice(2),m>"f")?b=n:c=n:a=p)&&d[a]?"":d[a]=a+" "+(b>c?`coal
`:b<c?`toys
`:`needs more data
`),d={}).join``
```

### Explanation

```js
s=>
  s.split`
`.map(l=>                   // for each line l of Santa's list
    l.split` `.map(p=>      // for each word p in l
      (m=p.match(/\w:\d+/)) // m = "y:x" for naughty, "e:x" for nice or null for name
        ?(n=+m[0].slice(2), // n = number at end of match
          m>"f")?b=n:c=n    // if naughty matched b = n, if nice matched c = n
        :a=p                // if no match, a = name
    )
    &&d[a]?"":              // if the name has been used before, add nothing to output
    d[a]=                   // else set d[name] to true

      // Add the appropriate text to the output
      a+" "+(b>c?`coal
`:b<c?`toys
`:`needs more data
`),

    // NOTE: This line is executed BEFORE the code above it in the map function...
    d={}                    // d = list of names that have been output
  )
  .join``                   // return the list of outputs as a string
```

### Test

```js
var solution = s=>s.split`
`.map(l=>l.split` `.map(p=>(m=p.match(/\w:\d+/))?(n=+m[0].slice(2),m>"f")?b=n:c=n:a=p)&&d[a]?"":d[a]=a+" "+(b>c?`coal
`:b<c?`toys
`:`needs more data
`),d={}).join``
```

```html
<textarea rows="5" cols="40" id="input">Quill naughty:4 nice:0
naughty:0 Doorknob nice:3
naughty:2 Quill nice:6
nice:3 balpha naughty:3
pops nice:4 naughty:2</textarea><br />
<button onclick="result.textContent=solution(input.value)">Go</button>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 64 bytes

```
qN/{S/':f/_{,1=},_@^$1f=:~:-g"needs more data
coal
toys"N/=S\N}/
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cU4ve1MvJzpmL197LDE9fSxfQF4kMWY9On46LWcibmVlZHMgbW9yZSBkYXRhCmNvYWwKdG95cyJOLz1TXE59Lw&input=UXVpbGwgbmF1Z2h0eTo0IG5pY2U6MApuYXVnaHR5OjAgRG9vcmtub2IgbmljZTozCm5hdWdodHk6MiBRdWlsbCBuaWNlOjYKbmljZTozIGJhbHBoYSBuYXVnaHR5OjMKcG9wcyBuaWNlOjQgbmF1Z2h0eToy)

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 329 Bytes - 25% bonus = 246.75

```
a={...}p={}u=" "k=ipairs for i=1,#a/3 do p[i]={}end for i,v in k(a)do p[math.floor((i+2)/3)][(v:find("y:")and 3)or(v:find("e:")and 2)or 1]=v:gsub("%a+%:","")end for i,v in k(p)do d=tonumber b,g,n=d(v[3]),d(v[2]),v[1]if(not u:find(" "..n.." "))then u=u..n.." "print(n..(g<b and" coal"or g>b and" toys"or" needs more data"))end end
```

Will edit in ungolfed version and explanations later, a bit tired at the moment. All input is taken in through command line, space separated.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, 206 bytes - 25% = 154.5

```python
s=[]
x=[0,0]
for p in zip(*(iter(input().split()),)*3):
 for w in p:
  j=w.find(':')+1
  if j:x[j<6]=int(w[j:])
  else:N=w
 b,g=x
 if N not in s:print N,['needs more data','coal','toys'][(b>g)-(g>b)];s+=[N]
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) 120 (160-25%)

Anonymous function using template strings, there are 4 newlines that are significant and included in the byte count

```
l=>l.split`
`.map(r=>k[r=r.replace(/\S+:(\d+)/g,(a,c)=>(t-=a[1]<'i'?c:-c,''),t=0).trim()]?'':k[r]=r+(t>0?` toys
`:t<0?` coal
`:` needs more data
`),k={}).join``
```